# PHP recursive function returns empty JSON object

Tags: php, json, laravel, recursion

I have a problem with a recursive function in PHP which returns a JSON object. When the the condition is met to run the function a second time I always get an empty object as result `{}`. Everything is executed as it would be in the first run, but I always get an empty result.

Here is my code (very much simplified, yet functioning):

```
public function run()
{
    $result = null;

    // .......
    // there is alot other stuff here, that all runs 
    // perfectly through also the second run
    // ......

    // Conditional Routing
    if($this->wfProfile->autoprocess){
        // select new wfProfile and go again.
        $this->autoprocess(function($data){
            if($data['error']==0){
                $result = null;
                $this->run(); // from here we start over !
            }else{
                return $data;
            }
        });
    }else{
        return ['error'=>0,'message'=>'all good']; // this is where it should go at the end of second loop
    }
}
```

There is no place in the whole class, that would return an empty JSON object. Something must be here, that I'm doing wrong or what I'm overseeing.

**Edit (I don't think this helps)**

```
private function autoprocess($callback)
{
    if(is_callable($callback)){
        $possibleWFprofiles = WfProfile::where('statusNow', $this->wfRequest->status)->where('conditionalRouting', 1)->get();
        if($possibleWFprofiles->count() == 0){
            // configuration error....
            $result = ["error"=>1, 'message'=>"Unable to find Conditional Routing enabled WfProfiles: ".$this->wfRequest->status];
        }
        foreach($possibleWFprofiles as $possibleWfProfile){
            if(array_search($possibleWfProfile->crFieldname, $this->wfRequestFields)===false){
                // fieldname wrongly configured
                $result = ["error"=>1, 'message'=>"Unable to find field ".$possibleWfProfile->crFieldname];
            }
            // see if this is the right one
            if($this->wfRequest[$possibleWfProfile->crFieldname] == $possibleWfProfile->crValue){
                  $this->wfProfile = $possibleWfProfile;
                  $result = ['error'=>0,'message'=>'Off to loop 2'];
            }
        }
        call_user_func($callback, $result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this method located in your app? There are some places in laravel that automatically json_encode your returns.

Comment: $result is used in the deleted code, but is not returned empty

Comment: after you call `$this->run()` it will ALWAYS return nothing because there is not return statement for it to hit.  YOU NEED `return $this->run()`

Comment: Yes it automatically JSON encodes it, it all works fine and returns the correct result if it doesn't do the second loop

Comment: @Popmedic the idea is to return whatever it hits on the second loop. Tell me how to do that

Comment: In your conditional you are returning $data in the else block, what are you assigning to data?

Comment: `return $this->run()`

Comment: $data contains ['error'=>1, some other stuff]

Comment: I tried return `$this->run()` it didn't work. I will try again to confirm

Comment: It could be one of the other methods you are running within that method. Have you checked those?

Comment: the `return $this->run()` returns empty `{}` as well. I checked all other methods, they are running through successfully on the second run, but nothing is returned from them. They would return always `['error'=>0, something else]` or error 1

Comment: Aw I see now, without seeing the `autoprocess` function, I am a little lost, but can you return the value from it (ie: `return this->autoprocess(...)`, you definitely are not returning from that if (`if($this->wfProfile->autoprocess){`)

Comment: `$data` is returned from that function

Comment: I don't think so, you are passing that block into `$this->autoprocess()` so it is returning $data to that function, and I can not see that function.

Comment: Since I thought initially, that this is the problem, I changed the function into a callback function, but it didn't make any difference to my empty result....

Comment: I added the function into the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make a `return $data`, inside a anonymous function, it will not be a run's return.

You are not doing nothing with this return in your `autoprocess` function.

You need to return something in `autoprocess` and then return in your if:

```
if($this->wfProfile->autoprocess){
    // select new wfProfile and go again.
    return $this->autoprocess(function($data){
        if($data['error']==0){
            $result = null;
            return $this->run(); // from here we start over !
        }else{
            return $data;
        }
    });
}else{
    return ['error'=>0,'message'=>'all good']; // this is where it should go at the end of second loop
}
```

Comment: But not only `return $this->run()`, he needs to return `autoprocess` as well. And adjust `autoprocess` function to return something :)

Comment: Yes I see that and tried to explain it to him.  Thank you for showing me how to better explain it! ;-)

Comment: This makes sense... although I changed my code already completely and returned something (as it was originally) from the $this->autoprocess() function. I will post it as an alternative here and accept this one as the correct answer and popmedic upvote for effort :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return your value, for example take this:

```
function callback($func, $val) {
    return call_user_func($func, $val);
}

function run($val) {
    if ($val < 10) {
        callback(function($val) { return run($val + 1); }, $val);
    } 
    return $val;
}

print(run(0));
```

this will print empty, but if you do:

```
function callback($func, $val) {
    return call_user_func($func, $val);
}

function run($val) {
    if ($val < 10) {
        return callback(function($val) { return run($val + 1); }, $val);
    } 
    return $val;
}

print(run(0));
```

it will print 10

Your function:

```
public function run()
{
    $result = null;

    // lets say this is true...
    if($this->wfProfile->autoprocess){
        // now we are here, where does this return a value???
        $this->autoprocess(function($data){
            // if it goes here, it never returns a value.
            if($data['error']==0){
                $result = null;
                $this->run(); // from here we start over !
            }else{ // if it returns here it still just returns to 
                   // $this->autoprocess, which might return to the
                   // original run function, but you don't seem to be
                   // returning its return either...
                return $data;
            }
        });
    }else{
        return ['error'=>0,'message'=>'all good']; // this is where it should go at the end of second loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end I chose the imho less elegant way to solve this, so I used `goto` instead of calling the function again. This is easy to read and to debug/extend in future. So here we go:

```
public function run()
{
  startover:
    $result = null;

    // more stuff going on here

    // Conditional Routing
    if($this->wfProfile->autoprocess){
        // select new wfProfile and go again.
        $result = $this->autoprocess();
        if($result['error']==0){
              goto startover; // easiest way :-)
        }else{
              return $result;
        }

    }else{
        return ['error'=>0,'message'=>'all good'];
    }
}
```

and here the autoprocess function

```
private function autoprocess()
{
    $possibleWFprofiles = WfProfile::where('statusNow', $this->wfRequest->status)->where('conditionalRouting', 1)->get();
    if($possibleWFprofiles->count() == 0){
        // configuration error....
        return ["error"=>1, 'message'=>"Unable to find Conditional Routing enabled WfProfiles: ".$this->wfRequest->status];
    }
    foreach($possibleWFprofiles as $possibleWfProfile){
        if(array_search($possibleWfProfile->crFieldname, $this->wfRequestFields)===false){
            // fieldname wrongly configured
            return ["error"=>1, 'message'=>"Unable to find field ".$possibleWfProfile->crFieldname];
        }
        // see if this is the right one
        if($this->wfRequest[$possibleWfProfile->crFieldname] == $possibleWfProfile->crValue){
            $this->wfProfile = $possibleWfProfile;
            return ['error'=>0,'message'=>'Off to loop 2'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally didn't like go to, but it works well! Good solution.